# where can we get memory consumption for karate-report folder files

Tags: karate

where can we get memory consumption for karate report folder files.Karate report folder contains lots of files please share some details on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Karate. You are welcome to contribute code to it since it is an open-source project.